# WPF DataGrid Binding properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an ItemSource that is bounded to a DataGrid. However, all of the properties of the ItemSource is being shown in the grid, but I have only specified a few columns (properties) that I want the user to see and modify in the XAML

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
       .. Column 1...
       .. Column 2...
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I am guessing there is a property of the grid that I will need to set to false so it only shows the columns or properties that I have personally specified.

If not, any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Basically I haven't added anything to the item source, so when the ViewModel is initialised, I initialise the collection in the ViewModel's constructor. So I guess this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **`AutoGenerateColumns=False`** on dataGrid and provide your own set of columns under **`Columns`** tag.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Of course. thanks! ( I will accept your answer but I need to wait a little while until I can )